# One thread ending the process

Tags: c, linux, multithreading

When a particular thread which is not main ends, I would like the parent process to end. How can i implement this?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `_exit` in that thread (instead of return) and the whole process will die.

Comment: Or perhaps call just `exit` to allow e.g. the handlers registered with `atexit` to run...